# How can I easily send a window to the back of a stack?

Tags: gnome, window-manager

I like to work with a number of apps open on a secondary monitor, one with a maximized window, and several more that are manually tiled in a particular way on top of them, just exposing a particular part of the maximized app so that I can see if it needs attention. I would like to be able to quickly and easily send the maximized window to the back of the stack when I'm done with it to reveal all the other windows I have there so I can focus on them instead. Right now I either alt-tab through the windows to bring them to front, or live with them being out of view for awhile, which is sub-optimal.

Suggestions as to how to achieve this? Something like an entry in the right-click menu on the title bar for "Send to back" would be great, but I'd settle for just about anything simpler than what I'm doing now.

Comment: On terminal I would use [`wmctrl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) (with something like`-v -r :ACTIVE:` ...) or `xdotool`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A middle click on the title bar should send the clicked window back.

If it is no longer available, it should be configurable depending on your window manager; use `gconf-editor` for metacity and clutter, `ccsm` for compiz.

Comment: which key in gconf-editor?

Comment: This post is dated. Nowadays it is dconf-editor. Use gnome-tweak-tool instead.

Answer (score 12):

The keyboard shortcut is disabled by default, but can be easily added.

[image]

Comment: Another good option!

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, this has changed.  I've attached a screen shot [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/190456306@N08/52406322231/in/dateposted-public).  Initially, it appeared to me that the function names were not sorted, but they are.  They are just separated into groups, each one preceded by a group title. I found that when I assigned the shortcut to the function, not only did the specified shortcut work, but the Windows 10 shortcut `Alt+Esc` also worked (it didn't before).