# XFCE Keyboard shortcut to place active window at the back (or minimize)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, window-manager

Is it possible to have a keyboard shortcut instead of middle-clicking the menu bar to lower windows behind all the others? Like the second answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65580/how-can-i-easily-send-a-window-to-the-back-of-a-stack) question, but in XFCE instead of Unity.

In case not, is there a keyboard shortcut for minimizing the active window?

Comment: Might seem obvious but I found `alt-tab` to be a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find all window manager shortcuts in System Settings → Window manager → Keyboard

- **Lower window**: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> To lower the window.

  It works fine with composite on, when it is off it seen to send it back on same monitor only (few windows, not back all windows)
- **Hide window**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> To minimize active window.
- **Switch application**: This seems to me having same effect of sending window to the back. Setup a shortcut and try it.

Comment: And in that same meny, there is `lower window` with `shift+alt+PgDwn`! Which is the command i was looking for

Comment: @JonatanÖström, good. I have tried that but i didn't included because It does not flip on all windows with dual monitor when composite is not active.

Comment: Ok, I see, I think is should be included anyway. It's a legit option.

Comment: shift+alt is usually bound to keyboard layout switch (ms windows legacy)

Answer (score 3):

#### Minimize the active window

Assuming you have `xdotool` installed (run `sudo apt-get install xdotool` if not), the command to minimize the active window is:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
```

Simply add that to a shortcut key and it should work. On XFCE: open Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts, add the command:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
```

#### Send a window to back?

To send a window to the last position from cli is a lot trickyer: currently, there is no (cli) tool to find out the z-order of the windows. Theoretically, you could raise all windows, *except* the active one, but this will most likely mess up the order of the windows.

***unless***
...you use [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/745813/72216), but if minimizing will do, I'd stick with the solution above.

Comment: Thanks JacobVlijm and @Sneetsher, that worked like a charm!

Comment: I thought I'd wait a couple days to see if a neat solution for placing at the back pops up. I think its preferable to avoid changing the accepted answer once its marked.